# Git SCM/Bash not prompting for Credentials on Windows

Tags: git, git-bash, git-clone, msysgit, git-config

I've executed `git config --system --unset credential.helper` and `git config --global --unset credential.helper` and gone in manually via `git config --system --edit` and `git config --global --edit` and all config is empty (just name and email).  I've also deleted all entries in Windows Credential Manager and rebooted my PC.

Whenever I attempt a clone, there is no prompt for credentials.  As a result, I get a 403 forbidden message.  Others have successfully cloned with the same command+url.  Protocol is http to an internal server.  I don't understand why Git is not prompting for credentials when config doesn't have anything setup.  How do I make Git prompt me from credentials?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting your entries in the Credential Manager was good, but you still need to restore the credential helper if you want to see any prompt:

```
git config --global credential.helper manager
```

Then the next push will prompt you for your credentials and store them.